# Title for popup-menu in matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, title, popupmenu

I've made a **popup-menu** in *Matlab* using `uicontrol`, instead of using **GUIDE**. Here is my code:

```
figure; 
String = sprintf( '%d#', 1:5);
String(end) = [];
CString=regexp(String , '#' , 'split');
uicontrol('style','popupmenu' , ...
          'String' , CString  , ...
          'Position' , [100,400,100,24]);
```

But I don't know how can I put a subject for the popup-menu.

If anyone knows I'll appreciate for your help.

Thank You in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add **another** *ui object*, probably `text` or `edit` beside the **popup menu**:

(I personally rather `edit` since it looks nicer)

```
txt_obj = uicontrol(...
    'Style','edit',...
    'HorizontalAlignment','right',...
    'String', 'Something',...
    'Position' , [0,400,100,24],...
    'BackgroundColor', [.9 .9 .9],...
    'Enable','inactive');
```

I encourage you to use **normalized units** for ease of coding (positioning actually!).
For more info see [**position property if uicontrol object**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol_props.html#bqxoipv) and [**Positioning Figures**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/positioning-figures.html) (which has the same concept of positioning).

Answer (score 0):

First, set a figure handle:

```
h = figure;
```

Then, set the name of the window:

```
set(h,'Name','This is my title text');
```

Comment: Actually I'm looking for a title next to the popup.